# How to sort list of items based on date property?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
const questions = [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe4c6d5eca146adc895fa4"),
        "title" : "How to Toggle between adding and removing Ajax text",
        "date" : "2018-10-10T22:01:01+03:00",
        "questionerId" : "5bbda46a433ced65ac7c4699",
        "voteNumber" : 0,
    },
    ,
];
```

I have a list of questions and i want to sort them based on the date, moment.from(), propery. How to accomplish that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There are tons of ways to accomplish _sorting_.

Comment: I know some sorting techniques but sorting by date seems complicated for me.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  So the problem is that you're unsure if dateA is older than dateB, due to the moment.js format.  Is that correct?

Comment: Could you please confirm if the solutions we gave was good for you?

Comment: Sorry I'm late. It doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please specify what is not working?

Comment: It doesn't sort the questions in descending order.

Comment: I updated my answer, which now sort the array in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to parse date string with moment to sort the array. You can do it simply by sorting strings.

For this you could use f.e. [String.prototype.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
const questions = [{
       "_id" : "5bbe4c6d5eca146adc895fa4",
          "title" : "How to Toggle between adding and removing Ajax text",
          "date" : "2018-10-10T22:01:01+03:00",
          "questionerId" : "5bbda46a433ced65ac7c4699",
          "voteNumber" : 0,
 },
 {
          "_id" : "5bbe4c6d5eca146adc895fa4",
          "title" : "How to Toggle between adding and removing Ajax text",
          "date" : "2018-10-11T22:01:01+03:00",
          "questionerId" : "5bbda46a433ced65ac7c4699",
          "voteNumber" : 0,
 },{
       "_id" : "5bbe4c6d5eca146adc895fa4",
          "title" : "How to Toggle between adding and removing Ajax text",
          "date" : "2018-10-09T22:01:01+03:00",
          "questionerId" : "5bbda46a433ced65ac7c4699",
          "voteNumber" : 0,
 }];

console.log( questions.sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
questions.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
```

However, I would suggest to transform all date strings to Date instances before the actual sorting:

```
questions
  .map(q => ({ ...q, date: new Date(q.date) }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)
```